# No server remain buffer to edit for org-capture-extension

Tags: org-mode, web-browser

Update: I have fixed it, seem like we need `stranform-square-bracket-function` to due with "p" protocal

```
(use-package org
  :hook
  (org-mode . turn-on-visual-line-mode)
  :config
  (setq org-directory "~/org/capture/")
  ;; Capture templates for links to pages having [ and ]
  ;; characters in their page titles - notably ArXiv
  ;; From https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension
  (require 'org-protocol)
  (defun transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones(string-to-transform)
    "Transforms [ into ( and ] into ), other chars left unchanged."
    (concat 
     (mapcar #'(lambda (c) (if (equal c ?[) ?\( (if (equal c ?]) ?\) c))) string-to-transform)))
  (setq org-capture-templates `(
                                ("p" "Protocol" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes_" (shell-command-to-string "date +%F__%H-%M-%S_%Z")) "Inbox")
                                               "* %^{Title_and_tag}\nSource: [[%:link][%(transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones \"%:description\")]]\n#+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE\n\n\n%?") 
                                ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes_" (shell-command-to-string "date +%F__%H-%M-%S_%Z")) "Inbox")
                                 "* %^{Title_and_tag}\n [[%:link][%(transform-square-brackets-to-round-ones \"%:description\")]]\n")
                                )))
```

Above is working org config of myself. Thank everyone

*Old*

This question with the similar content can be found in 2018 but until now there is no solution.
It is not the error because `(debug on error)` not show anything. It simply not work. And some time it work! I dont know why it suddenly work,and after i restart emacs it not work again!, there is just something wrong when firefox or emacs update. I am not professional on emacslisp so I cannot debug. The author of this extension don't update it after 1 year https://github.com/sprig/org-capture-extension.

```
;; Add org-protocol for org-capture

(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start));;for emacs client
(require 'org-protocol)
(setq org-modules (quote (org-protocol)))
;; org-capture templates
(require 'org-capture)
(use-package org-protocol
  :demand
  :config
  (setq org-capture-templates `(
                                ("p" "Protocol" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes.org") "Inbox")
                                 "* %^{Title}\nSource: %u, %c\n #+BEGIN_QUOTE\n%i\n#+END_QUOTE\n*** Tag is %^{Tag}%?")
                                ("L" "Protocol Link" entry (file+headline ,(concat org-directory "notes.org") "Inbox")
                                 "* %? [[%:link][%:description]] \nCaptured On: %U" :prepend t)
                                )))
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the question from 2018?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647948/getting-org-protocol-to-work-on-firefox-quantum-no-server-buffers-remain-to
and here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ai7hf0/does_anyone_here_still_use_orgprotocol/
And even in github issues have some threads about that.